# foreach and local commands

Tags: foreach, stata, local

I am trying to complete a `foreach` loop with a local string. However, I get `local not found` error. I want to only `keep` observations that include the following postal codes.

I am following the local example in the Stata help file and my variable postal code is in string format. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
local postal_cleveland "28086 28150 28152 28021 28090 28114 28073 28020 28017 28151 28169 28089 28038 28042 28136" 

foreach x in local postal_cleveland {

keep if strpos(postal_code, `x')

} 
local not found
r(111);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which help file you're alluding to, but there are several errors here, and you have been thrown out by the first. The loop should start

```
foreach x of local postal_cleveland {
```

The keywords `of` and `in` are not interchangeable.

What you typed with `in` is legal as any list can follow `in`, but when you get inside the loop Stata can only interpret `local` as the name of a string variable or scalar, but you have none such: hence the error message.

Another error has not yet bit you, but should be fixed now. When you are looking for a literal string inside a string variable, you must use `" "` to delimit the string; otherwise as just seen Stata can only guess that you are giving it the name of a string variable or scalar. So, you need

```
keep if strpos(postal_code, "`x'")
```

Yet another error has not yet bit you, but should be fixed now. As soon as you go

```
keep if strpos(postal_code, "28086")
```

Stata will follow your instructions *and so observations with all the other postal codes will disappear*. Then Stata will keep on going and on next seeing

```
keep if strpos(postal_code, "28150")
```

it again will follow your instructions. But there are no such observations: you `drop`ped them by implication on the previous iteration. So, now you have no data whatsoever and cannot then do anything useful.

You could avoid the loop altogether and just go

```
keep if strpos(postal_code, "28086") | strpos(postal_code, "28150") | ...
```

where the `...` imply other calls with different codes. That is just my shorthand because I won't type them out here; it is not Stata syntax!

Or you could use a loop and build up to one (and only one) `keep` statement.

That could be

```
gen tokeep = 0 

foreach x of local postal_cleveland { 
    replace tokeep = 1 if strpos(postal_code, "`x'")
} 

keep if tokeep
```

which I recommend as better style.

Otherwise put, `keep` acts instantly: it `keep`s observations satisfying the criteria specified and thus `drop`s all others.

Detail: string here means string storage or variable type; string as a (display) format by coincidence only implies the same variables.

Comment: This is great advice! One thing that could be added is to avoid using `strpos` since these are zip codes and matching fully on the value should be computationally more efficient. if zip+4 could appear in the data, then using strpos could in some cases generate an erroneous signal (since it's looking for any substring).

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev   Thanks for the very positive comment. I don't quite follow your comment on zip codes; I am British and don't deal with them in practice. I guess you're referring to versions with more digits.  Perhaps you could spell it out for the benefit of the OP in another answer?

Comment: Or couldn’t the comparison be limited to the first 5 characters of the zip?

Comment: Thank you, @Nick Cox! Actually, I started writing an answer (will post shortly), but realised it's not an issue due to a "-" symbol that is usually placed between zip and the additional 4 digits of the extended zip. So... I think my previous comment is safe to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

The comment below will apply only in a very special case when the data can contain zip codes with the additional 4 digits (zip+4) and these additional digits are not separated from the main zip code. This is unlikely to be observed, but possible if for example the data was parsed from a website and the dash symbol was ignored. As such, the comment below should be safe to ignore, but just posting this to elaborate on the thought process.

The idea is that `strpos(s1,s2)` function returns non-zero if value if `s2` appears anywhere within `s1`. If the variable containing zip codes has zip+4 without dashes (again, this is a very specific scenario, unlikely to be of general interest), then the function would return false matches.

For example:

Zip code `34265` is a location in Florida.
Zip code `60103` is a location in Illinois. A more precise zip inside Illinois is `60103-4265` (it's a post office there). If somehow this was recorded as `601034265`, then using `strpos` would indicate a match.

In general, to avoid similar issues with partial matches, for fixed-width data it makes sense to do a literal comparison using `==` rather than `strpos`.

Comment: As previously commented. restricting comparison to the first 5 characters would seem sufficient here.